# Angularjs routing conflict with MVC routing

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing, angularjs-routing

My MVC webpage have two links for "**Dashboard**" and "**ManageClient**" pages.
When I directly set route path to my AngularJS page(ManageClient), my "new client" template shows in `<div ng-view="">` perfectly.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "SubMClientManagement", action = "ManageClient", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

>>>> link in browser : http://localhost:55542/#/newClient
```

BUT;


If I set it to Dashboard, and go to ManageClient page and click newClient button it will not work

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "SubMClientManagement", action = "Dashboard", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    //defaults: new { controller = "SubMClientManagement", action = "ManageClient", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

>>>> link in browser : http://localhost:55542/SubMClientManagement/ManageClient/#/newClient
```

---

FYI

ang. route config :

```
ClientMngModel.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
        .when("/newClient", {
            controller: "NewClientController",
            templateUrl: "Templates/ClientMngTemp/NewClient.html"
        })
        .when("/deleteClient", {
            controller: "DeleteClientController",
            templateUrl: "Templates/ClientMngTemp/DeleteClient.html"
        })
        .when("/updateClient", {
            controller: "EditClientController",
            templateUrl: "Templates/ClientMngTemp/UpdateClient.html"
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });
}]);
```

---

In View : SubMClientManagement/ManageClient.cshtml

```
<a href="#/newClient" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
```

---

Ver:
angularjs.1.2.27
Mvc 4.0

Comment: Simple thing to do :-) : templateUrl: "../../Templates/ClientMngTemp/DeleteClient.html"